# Replace bottom navigation view with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have MainActivity with BottomNavigationView like so:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

Also, I have a setting button on top of the navigation view. On this button click, I wish the setting fragment appear on top of the navigation fragment and hide it and display the setting in full screen.

Something like so:

```
val settingsFragment = SettingFragment.newInstance()
val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
fragmentTransaction.replace(/*what to user here*/, settings)
fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
val navHostFragment
        = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
navHostFragment.childFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(navHostFragment.id, SettingsFragment())
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
```